# Skipping IF statement?

Tags: ada

I am so close to finishing one of the exercise in my book but I cannot fathom why this 'if' statement is being skipped. Everything else works, it compiles fine with no warnings. If I enter something over 1.00, it totally skips the part of the code that should handle that and returns the value 0.00. If I enter 24.00 or over (which are both handled within the same code block), it works fine and produces the expected output.

Here is my code, I have purposely marked the place where the code skips. I have been looking over it for over an hour and just do not know why it's not executing that part of the code, even though the value I pass to it is correct according to the condition. Really appreciate any help or advice you can give me.

Wishes Ada x

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

-- procedure main - begins program execution
procedure main is
   carTime : Float := 0.00;
   EXIT_FLAG : constant Float := 999.00;
   payment : Float;

-- function calculatePayment - calculates and returns the total charge for a
-- a car staying in the car park based on stay time
function calculateCharges(carTime : in Float; paye : out Float) return Float is
   BASE_CHARGE : constant Float := 2.00;
   DAY_CHARGE : constant Float := 10.00;
begin
   -- standard charge if one hour or less
   if carTime <= 1.00 then
      paye := BASE_CHARGE;
   end if;
   
   -- full day charge
   if carTime = 24.00 then
      paye := DAY_CHARGE;
   end if;
   
   -- calculate extra payment if time exceeds given parameters
   if carTime > 1.00 and carTime > 24.00 then
      declare
         EXTRA_CHARGE : constant FLoat := 0.50;
         timeOverHour : Float := 0.00;
         overPay : Float := 0.00;
      begin
         if carTime > 1.00  and carTime < 24.00 then  <===== THIS NEVER EXECUTES
            timeOverHour := carTime - 1.00;
            overPay := timeOverHour * EXTRA_CHARGE;
            paye := BASE_CHARGE + overPay;
         end if;
         
         if carTime > 24.00 then
            timeOverHour := carTime - 24.00;
            overPay := timeOverHour * EXTRA_CHARGE;
            paye := DAY_CHARGE + overPay; 
         end if;
      end;
   end if;

   return paye;
end calculateCharges;

begin
   New_Line;

   Put("Enter a stay time (enter 999.00 to quit): ");
   carTime := float'value(Get_Line);

   while carTime /= EXIT_FLAG loop
      Put("Total charge is: ");
      Put(calculateCharges(carTime, payment), Fore => 2, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      New_Line;

      Put("Enter a stay time (enter 999.00 to quit): ");
      carTime := float'value(Get_Line);
   end loop;

   New_Line;
end main;
```

Comment: your problem is in the preceding if statement, `if carTime > 1.00 and carTime > 24.00 then`

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to spot what I was going wrong - I had a logical 'and' which should of been logical 'or' and '>' should of been '<' :)

Comment: Probably worth your while learning how to use the debugger

Comment: Friendly tip: instead of using `and`/`or` and `<`/`>` for things like this, use ranges: `if carTime in 1.00..24.00`.